# iFrame loading twice in asp AjaxToolkit TabContainer

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel, ajaxcontroltoolkit

am using `asp AjaxToolkit` in my prjoect as below `asp.net C#` code.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanelDemo" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <ajax:TabContainer ID="tabMessage" runat="server" ActiveTabIndex="1" AutoPostBack="true"
                OnActiveTabChanged="tabMessage_ActiveTabChanged" CssClass="ajax__tab_blueGrad-theme">
                <ajax:TabPanel ID="TabMCompose" runat="server">
                    <HeaderTemplate>
                        <span style="padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 5px;">Compose </span>
                    </HeaderTemplate>
                    <ContentTemplate>
                    This Text not flickering or not loading twice // ***** 
                        <iframe id="IFrmCompose" runat="server" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" height="400px"
                            width="100%"></iframe>
                    </ContentTemplate>
                </ajax:TabPanel>
                <ajax:TabPanel ID="tabMInbox" runat="server">
                    <HeaderTemplate>
                        <span style="padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 5px;">Inbox (<span id="SpnIn" runat="server"></span>)</span>
                    </HeaderTemplate>
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <iframe id="IFrmInbox" runat="server" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" height="400px"
                            width="100%"></iframe>
                    </ContentTemplate>
                </ajax:TabPanel>
            </ajax:TabContainer>
        </ContentTemplate>
   </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

**Problem:** When I use `iFrame` inside the ajax `TabContainer` and when the user moves from 1st Tab to 2nd Tab, it seems that the page load twice and `iFrame` load twice or it flickers but the text above the `iFrame` as shown above ('**This Text not flickering or not loading twice**') is not flickering.

It seems there is some problem with `iFrame` and `Ajax TabContainer`.

Please give me suggestion why this happens.

Thanks.

Comment: `OnActiveTabChanged` event trigger, reloads `UpdatePanel`, as a result iframe contentWindow loading again, we can't observe much delay in static text or small fragment of plain html tags rendering. And whats happening in `tabMessage_ActiveTabChanged` method?

Comment: @VenkataPanga - in `tabMessage_ActiveTabChanged`  I assign the `Src` for all `iFrames` like `IFrmCompose='somepage.aspx'; IFrmInbox='someOtherpage.aspx';`

Comment: use [UFrame](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26330/UFrame-goodness-of-UpdatePanel-and-IFRAME-combined)

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% sure because there is no codebehind attached, but it looks like a ViewState issue. Since you are not setting the IFrame SRC in the repeater template, the page init will first set the IFrame empty and then re-set the URL even if it not changed (causing it to flicker).

Suggestion: Persist the URL in ViewState or other when a tab is changed, and set it in the repeater template to the persisted value. Always set any empty frame SRC to "about:blank" to avoid unnecessary loading and to reliably detect changes.

*Just a side note: in a way you are doing the same thing twice - with UpdatePanels/Ajax Controls you do not need IFrames, the contents of your tab should retrieved via an AJAX call thus making the IFrames obsolete.*

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% sure because there is no codebehind attached, but it looks like a ViewState issue. 
Page reload maybe the reason of the behavior

if(!IsPostback)
   BindIt();